# Нужно распараллелить программу по стандарту OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, распараллеливание, openmp

Программа находит количество компонент связности графа при помощи DSU. Нужно распараллелить её на несколько ядер.
Есть идеи?
(Я понимаю, что возможно будет необходимо переписать некоторые функции с С++ на С)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MaxSize = 1000;
int rep[MaxSize], mult_size[MaxSize];
void MakeSet(int x)
{
    rep[x] = x;
    mult_size[x] = 1;
}

int Find(int x)
{
    if (rep[x] == x) return x;
    else return (rep[x] = Find(rep[x]));
}

void Unite(int x, int y)
{
    x = Find(x);
    y = Find(y);
    if (x != y)
    {
        if (mult_size[x] > mult_size[y])
            swap(x, y);
        rep[x] = y;
        mult_size[y] += mult_size[x];
    }
}

int ConnectedComponentsAmount()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        MakeSet(i);
    int ver_1, ver_2;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> ver_1 >> ver_2;
        Unite(ver_1, ver_2);
    }

    bool used[MaxSize];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        used[i] = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        used[Find(i)] = true;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (used[i]) count++;

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    cout << ConnectedComponentsAmount();
    return 0;
}
```